# homestead vagrant up suddenly gives error

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

i suddenly get this error while trying to boot up my homestead server with vagrant up. Saw an identical issue here but the answer wasn't descriptive for me to follow.

```
C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:168:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
        from C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:168:in `block (2 levels) in configure'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:324:in `provision'
        from C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:167:in `block in configure'
        from C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:156:in `each'
        from C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:156:in `configure'
        from C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's in your vagrantfile on line 30?

Comment: thanks..i finally got it working, was an insertion error in my homestead.yaml file